# Making a tab visible but inaccessible in R Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny

I have this application that is working on a 4Gb RAM Shiny server but I have also uploaded it on shinyapps.io (which is limited to 1Gb RAM). The problem is that one of the tab will always make the app crash. In fact, this tab needs more than 1Gb of RAM in order to run.

So I wanted to kknow if there was a way to let the app like it is, with all the tabs visible for the user (so he knows what the app can do with a good server). But also to make one of the tabs unaccessible. What I mean is that the user can navigate through all the tabs except when he overs on the specific crashing tab, there is a little no entry sign which pops for the user. So he can't click just on this tab, but he still sees it.

Thx, I think it is impossible to do, but we never know ! Maybe with some Javascript or CSS !

Something like this with all my tabs :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A bit hack but working example

## ideas

1) add id to all tabs and hrefs ( create function for it)

2) disable it

## Example

Disable tab Table on actionbutton ( i dont know how you wnat to estimate "good server" so tab disabled manualy)

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)


server<-shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$disable,{
    disable("Table")
    disable("Table_")
  })

})
add_id=function(ss){

  ss$children[[1]]$children=lapply(ss$children[[1]]$children,function(i){
    i$attribs=list(id=i$children[[1]]$attribs["data-value"][[1]])
    i$children[[1]]$attribs=c(i$children[[1]]$attribs,id=paste0(i$children[[1]]$attribs["data-value"][[1]],"_"))
    return(i)
  })
  return(ss)
}


ui<-shinyUI(fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    actionButton("disable","disable"),
    add_id(tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Plot", h1("1")), 
      tabPanel("Summary", h1("2")), 
      tabPanel("Table", h1("3"))
    ))

))
runApp(list(ui=ui,server=server))
```